# For loop through ManyToMany field in Django view returns only the first Query

Tags: python-3.x, django

**I want to iterate through ManyToMany field of an object in my views getting the sum of all query sets**

But, what happens is that i got an error because the for loop got only the first query result and gives an error of operand + can not be between none and decimal values!!

Here Is My Code:

models.py

```
class TourPackage_trip(models.Model):
    trip_Price_EGP = models.DecimalField(default=0, null=True, max_digits=15,decimal_places=2)

class TourPackage(models.Model):
    trips = models.ManyToManyField(TourPackage_trip)
```

views.py

```
def PayNowTourPackageView(request, tour_id, buyer_id):
    tour = TourPackage.objects.get(id=tour_id)
    trips = tour.trips.all()
    for trip in trips:
         trip_fees += trip.trip_Price_EGP
```

*Any Help For That Will Be Thankful*

Answer (score 0):

Finally this method worked fine and I got the required results.

Actually still confused, cause i do not know why the first way is not working normally!

*Some Explanations Should Be Helpful*

views.py

```
    trips = tour.trips.all()
    trip_f = [int(trip.trip_Price_EGP) for trip in trips]
    trip_fees = sum(trip_f)
```